# Can i make css animation one at a time when window load?

Tags: html, css, animation, button, window

I tried to make one button fade in then the other follow up. Is there any way that i can achieve wat i trying to do? 
if there is way or any article, please help me know how to make one by one button animate at a time when window load?

HTML

```
        <li class="li">
        <a href="">
        <img class="image" src="http://templateafiq1.site88.net/button/about%20me.png">
        </a></li>

        <li class="li">
        <a href="">
        <img class="image" src="http://templateafiq1.site88.net/button/about%20me.png">
        </a></li>
    </center>
    </ul>
</font>
```

CSS

```
div header{
width:100%;
height:50px;
top:50px;
position:fixed;}

header .image{
height:110px;
width:110px;
opacity:0;

-moz-animation: fadein 2s;
-webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
-o-animation: fadein 2s;
animation-timing-function:linear;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
-webkit-animation-delay:1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;}

#header .ul{
list-style-type: none;
position:fixed;
top:17px;
width:100%;}

header .li {
height:110px;
width:110px;
padding:1px;
display:inline;
z-index:1;}

#header .li a{
text-decoration:none;
height:110px;
width:110px;}

//Fade in effect
@keyframes fadein {
0% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:1;}}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { 
0% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:1;}}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
0% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:1;}}
@-o-keyframes fadein { 
0% {opacity:0;}
100% {opacity:1;}}
```

Javascript

```
$(window).load(function() {
$("#header.image").fadeIn("fast");});
```

here the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pkjfgfpf/

Sorry for the bad english, english is not my native language.
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to the `fadeIn` function is a function to call once the animation is complete.  You can use this to chain animations to only happen after a previous animation is complete.  See the [fadeIn documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) for details.

HTML:

```
<img class="image" id="img1" src="imageUrl.filetype" />
<img class="image" id="img2" src="imageUrl.filetype" />
<img class="image" id="img3" src="imageUrl.filetype" />
```

JQuery:

```
$("#img1").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $("#img2").fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $("#img3").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    display: none;
}
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkjfgfpf/1/) (with all non-relevant parts removed)

Answer (score -1):

Probably this could be your solution, Adjust it in your code (see the example here `http://jsfiddle.net/nepal12/8jjooaox/`)

```
// HTML
<div id="images">
<img src="img1.jpg" alt="">
<img src="img2.jpg" alt="">
<img src="img3.jpg" alt="">
<img src="img4.jpg" alt="">
</div>

// Css
div#images { font-size: 0; background: #000; }
div#images img { width: 50%; height: auto;
opacity: 0; transition: .8s opacity; }
div#images img.visible { opacity: 1; }

// Javascript

<script>
var images = document.querySelectorAll("#images img"), i = 1;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, function(images) {
setTimeout(function(){ images.classList.add("visible") }, 700*i)
i++;
})

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
$('#header.image').fadeIn('fast');
```

To:

```
$('.image').each(function(index,domEle){ 
      setTimeout(function ( ) { 
                                if(domEle.style.webkitAnimationPlayState!=undefined && domEle.style.webkitAnimationPlayState != null) 
                                { 
                                       domEle.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'running'
                                } 
                                if(domEle.style.mozAnimationPlayState!=undefined && domEle.style.mozAnimationPlayState != null) 
                                { 
                                       domEle.style.mozAnimationPlayState = 'running'
                                } 
                                if(domEle.style.oAnimationPlayState!=undefined && domEle.style.oAnimationPlayState != null) 
                                { 
                                       domEle.style.oAnimationPlayState = 'running'
                                } 
                                if(domEle.style.msAnimationPlayState!=undefined && domEle.style.msAnimationPlayState != null) 
                                { 
                                       domEle.style.msAnimationPlayState = 'running'
                                } 
                                if(domEle.style.animationPlayState!=undefined && domEle.style.animationPlayState != null) 
                                { 
                                       domEle.style.animationPlayState = 'running'
                                } 
                             },index*2000); 
  });
```

At your CSS styles simply add the following:

```
header .image{
   animation-play-state:paused;
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
   -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
   -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
   -o-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

sample Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pkjfgfpf/